# Why was this question closed as too localized?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I do not believe [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243634/fibonacci-for-odd-and-even-numbers-proof-induction) deserved to be closed as too localized. The question is a valid question and by no means too localized.

The OP has again posted the same question an hour back [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243893/having-problem-in-proving-fibonacci-for-even-and-for-odds) and it has received couple of answers.

Also, as discussed [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/634/use-of-moderator-power-to-close-questions?rq=1), in general, I believe that moderators should wait for at least couple of votes to close a question from non-moderator users before closing a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was requested to be closed by the OP. "Too localized" was just the least objectionable. It was then subsequently [asked again](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/243893/).

I will delete the original now.

Comment: Ok. I did not find any comment by the user asking to close the question and hence the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Marvis: It was flagged, so there was no comment.

Comment: Ok. Thanks rob.

Comment: @robjohn: I think that it is best to leave a comment "Closed after the request of the OP", or something.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: true. I will do that (but not on this one since I would have to undelete and reopen to add the comment).

Comment: Just undelete actually... and obviously not on this one. Although you can always edit the deleted question without it bumping to the top of the front page. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I am a bit annoyed that the OP had me close the question only so that they could repost it. I don't want to inadvertently bump the post.

Comment: But... editing a deleted question won't bump it. That's the point I was trying to make in the second part of the comment.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I know, but it is deleted. I have added a banner so that it stays deleted.

Comment: @robjohn Yes. It is weird that the OP decided to repost the question.