# Should we allow moderators to unilaterally close questions?

Tags: discussion, policy, moderators, closing

At least one moderator has been unilaterally closing questions (e.g. with the first vote, for "missing context"). In the past, it has always been agreed that moderators should only use unilateral closing powers in cases where there can be no question about the decision (e.g. blatant spam). For other matters (and esp. for contentious matters), the community should use the SE-designed process to close and reopen posts as the community sees fit. Such decisions should not be made by a single member of the community. Do we still agree about this?

For those who many not be aware of the history. In the early days of MSE we did have serious problems with moderators closing questions that they *personally* felt were off-topic, e.g. too applied, or too elementary, or too computational, or too foundational, etc (questions that would surely be considered on-topic nowadays).

Thanks to Martin for pointing out a [recent thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11667/242) by Brian M. Scott about essentially the same issue (I was not here when that was posted).  There Brian refers to such unilateral closures as an "abuse of [moderator] powers", a sentiment that I strongly agree with. This may well be the reason that we lost Brian. It was the reason that I left the site last year. I am very sad to see that not only do these problem still remain, but they've gotten much worse. How unfortunate for MSE.

Comment: Is it possible for moderators to vote to close without automatically closing it (i.e., voting as a regular user)? If not, why not?

Comment: Was there *really* a question about its fate? I mean this question seriously: I haven't paid careful enough attention to actually have realistic knowledge about the distribution of life cycles of such questions.

Comment: @Hurkyl The question is about *general policy*, not about the fate of any particular question. And, fyi, some members of the community strongly disagree with the homework/psq views held by some users, and we have lost some very knowledgeable mebers of the community due to this discord.

Comment: I propose, *as general policy*, that if there is no question that the fate of a question is to be closed, then its fine for it to be closed unilaterally.

Comment: @Hurkyl Any such decisions should be made by the *community*, not by a single member using a *unilateral, binding* vote.

Comment: (if this topic is about whether or not there is a question that the fate of questions like the example is to be closed, then you should actually say so, rather than couch it as a question about the general policy regarding questions for which there is no question. Otherwise, I will continue to respond to what is actually written)

Comment: @Mike No, it's [status-declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41062/).

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/634/use-of-moderator-power-to-close-questions and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11667/unilateral-closure-by-moderator

Comment: @127.0.9.6 I don't see any reason given there that it should be declined. This appears to have been during SE1.0; perhaps it could be resuggested now?

Comment: For people who didn't click through, the recent thread linked is about a weird corner case, which is that moderators should not close *migrated* questions (even as the 5th vote!) outside of really extreme situations.

Comment: "It was the reason that I left the site last year." Is there a reason you came back after exactly one year?

Comment: @Noah Wrong. As Brian emphasized his point is "the fundamental problem of one person preempting the community remains; another instance may be seen [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568397/find-the-limit-without-use-of-lhopital-or-taylor-series)." That shows an example closed on the *first* vote, by the same moderator.

Comment: @Michael Because I had hoped that the newer moderators would not repeat the same mistakes of a few long gone.

Comment: Bill, while I do agree that in general unilateral closure is not a good idea, I also recall that we always had a very fundamental disagreement on what counts as "reasonable" in this aspect. This is like saying that murder is the worst thing you can do in any possible scenario; without taking into account that sometimes you kill someone because they are shooting at you (it's not good all of a sudden, but it's not as bad as premeditated murder). And I feel that there is a very strong consensus that indeed unilateral closure is bad; but the real issue is *when* it becomes acceptable. [...]

Comment: [...] And it always bothers me in these discussions, that the focus was on the generality, which the majority of people already agreed upon, rather than the particularity which is where the disagreement lies. And the real issue was that all the ensuing discussions in comments of such threads were always thinly veiled discussions on the particular case, and rarely on the general case.

Comment: To reiterate, my concern here is only with the general matter of unilateral closure - not with the details of any specific case. Given past history, I think it is very dangerous to let any single user make unilateral decisions on site content. This should be done by the community inasmuch as possible.

Comment: @Bill: "inasmuch as possible" is too far; you're throwing the baby out with the bathwater. It would entail, for example, moderators leaving spam for the community to deal with.

Comment: @Hurkyl Not true. Please read what I wrote in the question, where i explicitly mentioned "blatant spam" as an example of posts that could be handled unilaterally, since there is no disagreement in the community about such.

Comment: Eh? Are you withdrawing "done by the community inasmuch as possible" then? Claiming that it's impossible for moderators to leave spam to the community? Are you sticking with a double standard that "done by the community inasmuch as possible" only applies when it suits your fancy? Something else? (note the previous comment was edited after the previous text was written) I'm pretty sure there is *some* disagreement in the community, *even about spam* -- e.g. I'm pretty sure the spammers would prefer their posts not to be deleted!

Comment: @hurkly No, I expect any reader this far into the comments to have read what I wrote in the question, so that the context will clarify any potential natural language ambiguities. Please stay focused on the matter at hand, which has nothing to do with spam, as is clear to anyone who read the first sentence of my question.

Comment: I pick this nit because it is *directly* relevant to the topic. Tossing out an absolute proscription against moderators closing threads is inappropriate when the central topic discussion is about the extent to which moderators should close threads. If that's the topic you actually want to discuss, then discuss it!

Comment: Again, no *absolute proscription* was proposed, as is plain as day to anyone who bothered to read the first sentence of my question. Please read the question before leaping to absurd inferences.

Comment: @Bill: Yes. You phrase words that sound absolute, and then ask the reader to decide for themselves how to resolve the "natural language ambiguities". Surely you can see how this would fail to clarify your actual opinion?

Comment: @Hurkyl I don't know why you cannot understand what was said quite clearly in the first sentence of my question. Don't expect any further replies from me when you make such absurd claims completely contrary to what I have written.

Comment: I can't figure out the relevance to divining your opinion of a statement of fact that one or more moderators have closed more than one question unilaterally.

Comment: Anyways, my proposition is meant to be a direct, practical translation of the condition you suggested: "no question about the decision" -- if it is certain that the community will decide to close a question, then it is appropriate for a moderator to close it unilaterally. This practical criterion seems more appropriate than attempting to hash out closing criteria in a theoretical manner. I'm not sure if this intent was conveyed; your response made it sound like you had something very different in mind.

Comment: @Hurkyl The point is that there is no one in the community who questions the topicality of spam. But there are members of the community who disagree widely on the very subjective criteria used to judge how much (if any) effort needs to be shown when posing questions. As such, no individual should be making that decision for the entire community.

Comment: The spammers do! More generally, any community decision will have *some* people disagree with it. I did not propose for moderators make decisions for the community, but to observe empirically what sorts of things the community has decided should be closed. I took great pains to state a criterion that can be applied generally, rather than in an ad-hoc fashion, and in a way that makes no reference to the implied topic of PSQ -- in fact, as I said with my initial comment, I do not even know if PSQ meet this criterion!

Comment: Bill, my advisor, whom I think is a wonderful teacher and a lecturer often says that it is a good idea not to discuss the most general theorem, if it obscures understanding. The same holds here. You wish to discuss the "most general settings", and in that settings the answer is simple "No, it's not a good idea. Yes, there should be exceptions." But now we're stuck on what are the exceptions, and that cannot be discussed in generality because it's a case to case problem that the moderators have to deal with each time anew. The gray area is huge, and I find your insistence counterproductive.

Comment: @Asaf The policy on meta has always been to abstract from the specifics. In any case, since this thread was long ago derailed by off-topic comments, I have given up any hope of discussing the actual issue I hoped to discuss. Long gone are the days when one can have constructive discussions on meta.

Comment: Bill, it's easy to claim that any comment which is not on the most general abstract is immediately off topic. Yes, my comments are not on the topic of your question. They are about your attitude. You insist and refuse to accept that there is a possibility that the abstract question has a simple and agreeable answer. But the problem is that you and I (or you and the moderators) disagree on the implementation. As long as you keep ignoring this fact, you will always be disappointed by the "lack of constructive discussions on meta". And that is a shame.

Comment: @Asaf I did not say anything about your prior comments. And what you have inferred about my beliefs is not true. However, the *prior* comment is off-topic.

Comment: I never said that you did say anything about my previous comments; I said something about my previous comments. As for my inference, it may be false. But that's how I understand your behavior, and I'm not sure where my mistake is (except for the fact that the function which takes beliefs to behavior often has discontinuities, so to speak, and this might as well be one on my side, or yours).

Comment: @Asaf *Again*, my only interest here is to discuss the topic in the question. If you wish to discuss other matters could you *please* do so elsewhere. The thread is already derailed enough as it is by comments having little to do with the matter I focused on in the question.

Comment: I posit that lamenting the alleged abuse of moderator power in specific instances is a rather poor way to start a discussion about the abstract question.

Comment: @Hurkyl That such abuses of power, and failure to reach good compromises are causing MSE to lose many significant contributors is, imo, a quite pertinent footnote to add to the question.

Comment: Dear @BillDubuque : We've shed contributors over the years, but quite often there isn't much information available on the specific reasons for leaving. Any sources you can provide that substantiate users leaving for "dissatisfaction with moderation" would be appreciated. I don't doubt that they exist, I just wonder about the true frequency of this reason. It does not seem like a major problem in the big scheme. Regards.

Comment: @rschwieb It is obvious in most cases, e.g. read the linked post of Brian and peruse some of his relatively recent comments. Other significant contributors have left over poor SE-level moderation, e.g. Robin Chapman. In almost all cases, we would have lost no one had the site been managed by folks with more experience in such matters. Unfortunately no one with such experience has volunteered for the job. I have tried to coax some such users into doing so, but most say that they do not have the patience to deal with all of the nonsense that comes with managing a general-level math site.

Comment: @rschwieb, in case you missed it, in the last 15 months or so the MSE meta has made a full blown transition to an adult kindergarten, changing its focus from optimizing the main site, to controlling and limiting user behavior.  The shark-jumping moment was when a world expert on Wiles' work on FLT was unable to post an answer to a question about that work (re: AC) because some of the aggressive meta users found it more important to punish the poster of the question by closing it, and the expert was stuck having to debate the idiocy in meta.

Comment: @BillDubuque I don't doubt you on B.M.S. and I'll take your word on R.S. but any more than these two that you could mention would be helpful as I look into the matter.

Comment: Dear @zyx Apparently I did miss it, but that's unsurprising considering I don't spend enough time in meta to notice such a trend. Is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618147/does-wiless-proof-of-fermats-last-theorem-essentially-use-axiom-of-choice) the subject of your anecdote? Regards.

Comment: @rschwieb, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11219/on-hold-question/11222#comment42504_11222 .  Investigations of the kind you might be considering are obstructed by the phenomenon ( discussed at  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10926/another-valuable-user-leaves-mse-why/10949#10949 )  that when a departure does take place there are calls (some sincere and others less so) to "respect privacy" and not talk about the event .

Comment: Yes, that's the AC thread, and there were related events on Mathoverflow and its meta.  @rschwieb

Comment: @zyx I'm very sad, but not surprised, to learn of  [André's Nicolas's comment](http://goo.gl/aNLixB) that his "interest in participating in MSE has been **profoundly affected**" (his emphasis). If he too leaves MSE then the top 3 rep users will all be gone, 40% of the top 10 rep users will have left at one point or another, and more than 60% will have ruminated about doing so. If that's not a wake up call to SE, then I imagine that nothing will be.

Comment: Dear @zyx oof, now this spans multiple sites and their metas... complicated. Right about the privacy issue too: I guess I should state that I'm only hoping for names which publicly announced that specific reason. I won't speculate on the rest, or ask anyone else to speculate. Regards.

Comment: Correction, the percentages I quoted are even higher, since one should include Robin Chapman, who was, and surely would still be in the top 10 rep users.

Comment: @Bill, there was also the disappearance of liberal "voices of reason" from the meta, such as JDH and (until very recently returning at a reduced participation rate) Matt E, and some high profile suspensions that allowed the pro-closing activists to face significantly less opposition than might otherwise have been the case. You (or 10k+) might be interested in the opinions expressed in my comments under this deleted question and its answer ( http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/what-is-math-se-policy-on-multiple-accounts )  about one of those cases.

Comment: Users have left -- or haven't even bothered to begin participating -- in MSE because of overly lax moderation too and/or users pushing for too broad of a scope. It's very misleading to pretend that the set of contributors to MSE is a monotonically decreasing function of the level of moderation activity. If you really want testimonials, then I myself left MSE for a time when it looked like the old status quo was going to continue to be *forced* upon us.

Comment: @Hurkyl I don't recall any users who left for that reason.

Answer (score 9):

If it's clear that the ultimate fate of a question is to be closed (or to be put on hold until improved) then I can see only drawbacks to requiring moderators to abstain from accelerating the process.

(EDIT: I knew I was missing an obvious one: an incidental increase in the number of mistakes. This is, of course, mitigated by the requirement of *clarity*)

As a preemptive measure, I feel I should point out "the ultimate fate is to be closed" is very different from "it is fated to go through a close/reopen war", "will accrue a few close votes but not actually be closed", and "I personally think questions like this do not belong on MSE". And that "it's clear" is *much* stronger than, say, "75% confidence".

Comment: After thought, I can see one possible drawback: if moderators become much quicker on the draw than the rest of the community, we could eventually get to a position where the "training data" for classifying the eventual fate of a question would become tainted.

Comment: I think another shortcoming might be that the window of opportunity for improving the question before closure shrinks.

Comment: @Michael: If you add in that there is lag before it gets reopened, I can see that. It could be mitigated if there was a fast way to quickly reopen questions when they are improved after being put on hold. I think there are a few possibilities to improve the response time; it would be interesting to make a new topic on it.

Comment: @Michael: ... but again going back to my lack of knowledge of the distribution of life cycles, do questions get improved before accumulating a fifth close vote?

Comment: Questions that are edited after being closed are put into the review queue for reopen votes, so *in theory* should be reopened quickly if the edit is good. I also don't know how well this works in practice though.

Comment: @Matt: I never knew that! I suppose that's because reopen votes don't give notification icons on my SE status bar.

Comment: @Hurkyl I learned it before the status bar appeared! I hadn't used the review queue for a while, but having just checked it, the only question under "reopen votes" had the description "this question was edited after being closed", so it appears this is still true. (Perhaps relevantly, the question was closed for lacking context and had been edited to include a lot more information about what the OP already does(n't) understand - I have voted to reopen!).

Answer (score 4):

Personally I do not feel comfortable with mods using their binding votes to close, delete or reopen a question. With the exception of spam and similar clear-cut cases, I think that moderator's vote should be as strong as votes of other members of the community.

Without implementing some changes by SE developers (which does not seem very probable) this is not very easy, but it is definitely not impossible.

- When reopening questions, mods used to post comments [in the re-open thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-votes) instead of voting. If there were enough comments from mods, that they wish to reopen, some of the mods cast their bounding vote and made a comment in that thread. (I suppose that the mods still proceed like this when reopening questions.)
- [This comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/634/use-of-moderator-power-to-close-questions?lq=1#comment1792_641) from 2010 (which was before my time at MSE) seems to indicate that mods used to post a comment that they think a question should be closed instead of casting a vote. I do not know when this practice stopped, but it seems like a reasonable possibility to me.
- Another possibility could be using dedicated chatroom for this (or use some of the chatrooms that already exists). But I think that this could become a little chaotic; I think that other possibilities are better.

I am aware that our moderators have a lot on their plates and I do not like the idea of adding even more work for them. But, as I said, unilateral closures do not seem right to me. Let us see what other members of our community think about this. (So, please, upvote or downvote this post to indicate your agreement/disagreement.)

Comment: I presume you agree with using binding votes to close spam.... If so, a worthwhile exercise is to imagine that you didn't already have a solid belief that spam is "fair game"; how would you arrive at that belief despite your discomfort with binding votes? *Would* you even be able to? I think these sorts of explanations are incredibly important in this sort of discussion; it makes all the difference between a reasoned opinion and a dogmatic "Power is bad! Nobody should have power, except when I say it's okay".

Comment: Ah, that wasn't meant as an attack; let me try to explain better. It's easy to just cite a general principle like "power is bad"; but it is also nearly content free: I think nearly *everyone* would agree that the more power one has and uses, the more potential for it to be used for harm. But there are clearly uses that outweigh the potential for harm. In a discussion about *just how much* power should be had/used, it becomes problematic to just cite the general principle, because it turns into a double standard: *your* opinion is bad because {principle}, although *my* opinions are exceptions.

Comment: ... which is why it is more productive to actually comment on why and how one thinks a line should be drawn in a particular place or what sorts of things should be on which side of the line; such a comment is what I was hoping to get as a response.

Comment: "*dogmatic* ... *nearly content free* ... *double standard* ... *power is bad* ... *"except when I say it's okay"*. --- that's at least **5** blatant misrepresentations, and I doubt @Hurkyl will be able to locate specific material in the answer that matches any of those negative descriptions.  The obvious thing to do would be to delete the comments, which would be just as well considering the silliness of the comparison between spam and mathematics questions.  If there is a real point to be made I'm sure it can be done in some other way.

Comment: @zyx: I would explain better what I meant... but I already did. :P  And who's making a comparison? I would be happy with *any* attempt to explain just what one thinks justifies an exception to the general principle: I only offer up spam as a test case since it's relatively uncontroversial that it should be an exception. (and that it serves as a relatively easy sanity check)

Comment: *"I already did [explain that]"*.  No, you did not explain any reason to call Martin's answer "dogmatic", or "content free", or to accuse him of applying a "double standard", or to claim that the answer (which does not include the word *power*) argues from the premise that "power is bad", or to present him as claiming personal command over which uses of power are "okay".  @Hurkyl

Comment: FWIW, my opinion changed a bit since I made this post. But it is probably better to leave the answer here, since the voting reflects (at least to some extent) position of other users at the time. (I have added this comment after seeing that this is discussed once again in comments to a recent question on meta.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak What is your opinion now?