# Are questions asking for various applications of some theory Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I've asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2874252/concrete-problems-that-can-be-solved-by-appealing-to-a-moduli-space) that does not admit a concrete answer. I will add the tag soft to it as well.

For questions regarding applications of certain topics, for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2293/applications-of-algebraic-topology), should they be made Community Wiki?

Of course there is a fine line to walk between a subject like "Algebraic topology" and "concrete applications of moduli spaces," but I'm still wondering if there is some consensus surrounding this ussue.

Comment: I think marking your question as **CW** is a *great* idea, in keeping with the other question you link to.  That is, when asking a question that admits of multiple correct answers, each with an application, you are in effect embarking on a community post:  Asking a question, and soliciting contributions that form a sort of "big list" from community members, can remain on ongoing and valuable CW post.  In such a scenario, since no one answer will contain every application possible, and invariably misses an application others may include, the post is, in effect, a community effort.

Comment: @amWhy hmmm.... It seems that I am actually unfamiliar with how CW works. Should I just write into the text of the question that this is something of a community wiki?

Comment: Just to be clear, for those unfamiliar with what CW means:  It is short for *community wiki*.  Every question asked, and every answer provided, contains, in the right, lower corner of one's post, a tiny box in which one can mark the post as "community wiki".

Comment: @amWhy I've removed "CW" from this question in title and body to make that clearer. Sorry about that.

Comment: See my comment immediately above, Andres.  Click on edit (as though you were going to edit your post).  Look in the rightmost, lower corner of the field, and you'll see a tiny box in which you can click *community wiki*.

Comment: @amWhy I'm not sure I can do that for questions. Or at least, I do not see said box.

Comment: Click on "edit". Look just below the text field box, on the right, in between your text field, and what is rendered below the text field.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Andres.  To make a *question* community wiki, you need to flag a moderator, select "for moderator attention" and request to make the post a community wiki post.  Answerers on most posts, are able to select the community wiki option for their answer only.

Comment: @amWhy:  Isn't there an issue with converting a Question that already has Answers to Community Wiki?  A CW Question will automatically have CW status on all Answers.  So you'd be asking any votes on existing Answers to be nullified (as far as reputation earned is concerned).  I'm not familiar with a practice of marking soft-question or big-list Questions as necessarily Community Wiki.

Comment: Closely related: [What questions should be community wiki?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/445/what-questions-should-be-community-wiki)

Comment: @hardmath that is a good point. It seems as though most answers actually turned out to be comments, so maybe it would be inconsequential. Thank you for the link, I read that and I thought it was helpful but I still felt slightly uneasy because in practice the CW stuff is not very uniform.

Comment: It is AFAIK entirely at the Question's author's option to make a CW Question.  I've made some CW Answers, but the early history of StackExchange provided that after a certain number of edits (by multiple hands), the post would become a Community Wiki.  However this policy ended years ago, it being agreed that it was counterproductive in discouraging edits for fear of triggering loss of reputation points.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/, https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/04/22/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227290/160917